# What version of MySQL is actually supported?

Tags: database, magento2.4

Was running Maria DB 5.5, tried to install Magento CLI 2.4.0, Amazon Linux / nginx Got this error.

`Sorry, but we support MySQL version 5.6.0 or later.`

Ok. So I install MySQL 5.6. It seems to be working, I get to

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 1282]
Required extensions check...
[Progress: 2 / 1282]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...
[Progress: 3 / 1282]
Installing deployment configuration...
[Progress: 4 / 1282]
Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_AdminAnalytics':
[Progress: 5 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_Store':
[Progress: 6 / 1282]
...
[Progress: 639 / 1282]
Installing search configuration...

In SearchConfig.php line 81:

  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

No problem. I install elasticsearch. Retry install, now it's saying that the minimum version is 5.7??

```
[Progress: 4 / 1282]
Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:

In SqlVersionProvider.php line 93:

  Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 5.6.23. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)
```

Comment: For some reason, deleting the database and rerunning `bin/magento setup::install` works, but otherwise if you re-run the install after it's created the schema, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 is the recommended version for use with 2.4, although they do support 5.7.

MySQL 5.6 isn't officially supported with 2.4, and was discouraged for use with 2.3

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#database

Comment: So, this should be fixed: `Sorry, but we support MySQL version 5.6.0 or later.` - it should say 5.7. Otherwise, it's a huge waste of time. `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:    const MYSQL_VERSION_REQUIRED = '5.6.0';`

Answer (score 0):

In case you really have to use MariaDB, you can force your way into skipping the version check. Do not do this if you're unsure that your version is supported, but I found this solution useful in my case.

The file `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Validator/DbValidator.php` has the line of code that retrieves the MySQL version:

`$mysqlVersion = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT version()');`

If you replace it with something that passes the validation, it will work. For example:

`$mysqlVersion = '5.7.0';`